# Sendgrid fails in Email->getHeadersJson()

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid

I'm currently facing a situation in production that is driving me crazy. I'm using `PHP 7.1`, `Laravel 5.5.26` and `Sendgrid 4.0.4`.

The piece of code that fails is:

```
 $this->email
            ->setFrom($from) // sender email
            ->setSubject(' ')
            ->setSmtpapiTos($recipients)
            ->setSubstitutions($params)
            ->setSections($sections)
            ->addCategory($category)
            ->addBcc($bcc)
            ->setText(' ')
            ->setHtml(' ')
            ->setFromName($name) // sender name
            ->setTemplateId($tempId); // id template email

 // send email
 $this->sendgrid->send($this->email);
```

The current error I get is as follow:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

and it comes from this:

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'count(): Parameter must be an
>   array or an object that implements Countable', 
>       '/app/vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid/lib/SendGrid/Email.php', 569, array())
>       at count(null) in Email.php (line 569)
>
> at Email->getHeadersJson() in Email.php (line 611)
>
> at Email->toWebFormat() in SendGrid.php (line 109)
>
> at SendGrid->send(object(Email))in EmailController.php (line 100)

I would appreciate any help.

**UPDATED**

I added ->addHeader('key', 'value') (dummy key-value pair) so the headers are not empty and it works properly.

Answer (score 3):

**Possible solution**

I just added *addHeader(key, value)* with a dummy key-value pair to the email so I try to avoid that the headers are empty.

The still don't understand why this is happening when Im using `PHP 7.1` and not `PHP 7.2`.